# LINQ where clause not returning results

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, where-clause, enumeration, dbset

Result set returns empty and i'm getting that error 'Enumeration yielded no results' when i use Where clause(LINQ) . What could be problem?

```
public class Stores
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int StoreId { get; set; }
    public string StoreName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public int TownId { get; set; }
}

public DbSet<Stores> Store { get; set; }

var storeList = from n in db.Store
                where n.TownId == 10
                select n;
```

Comment: Are you sure that there are any values in that db with `TownId == 10`, also how is the data generated?

Comment: Oh excuse me!Careless today :S Db has no specified value(10). Thanks for aid.

Comment: hahaha it totally happens to the best of us.